# node js помощь с pm2 и файлом yaml

Tags: node.js, yaml, pm2

Хостер меня перевел на систему pm2 - http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#yaml-format. Сказал создать файл yaml со своими приложениями и ими можно будет управлять через pm2 Читал документацию, но не все понял, создал файл yaml.yml:

```
apps:
   - script : /var/www/server/site/server.js
     name   : 'mySite'
     watch  : true
```

через ssh прописал `pm2 start all`, написало, что все процессы запущены и вывелась табличка с моим процессом и надписью online, но сайт не работает. А когда прописываю в ssh просто node server.js то все работает хорошо. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте командой `pm2 delete nameProcess` удалить все процессы из листа. Потом сделайте `pm2 unstartup`. Проверка процессов в списке модуля `pm2 list`. Если он чист - запустите все процессы заново, по одному `pm2 start nameProcess`. Проверьте, что все работает через `pm2 list`. Дальше `pm2 startup` и `pm2 save`.

Comment: pm2 unstartup и startup выводит [PM2][ERROR] Init system not found

Comment: а при pm2 list выводит │ site │ fork │ online  │ 0  │ 0%  │ 4.9 MB   │

Comment: Пробуйте дальше. Главное, чтобы ошибки не было, когда будете писать команду `pm2 startup`.

Comment: на команду стартуп такая же ошибка PM2][ERROR]

Comment: У  Вас  Windows  ?

Comment: там где сайт лежит? Там линукс, а я с windows

Comment: Я на Debian ставил все норм было. Попробуйте конкретно систему указать `pm2 startup linux`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72389/discussion-between-iryna-and-).